# how to build function values?

Tags: python, string, function

I'm developing a telegram bot which built the function graphics. In first, I take from the user the range on which graphic will build. In second, I take the fuction on string format (it like 'y=x**2' for example, later I cut 'y='). Then I'm calculate y-values by means of range which earlier took from the user.

For example:

```
x = 100
func = 'x**2' # cut the 'y='
y = [eval(func) for x in range(-100,100)]
```

Linear and quadratic functions don't creat the problems. How to calculate y-values for functions who have a region of admissible values (sqrt, log and etc)? Are there any libraries to help me with my problem or I need to write own string parcer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check module [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (for `Symbolic Math`)

Answer (score 0):

You should check module [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (for `Symbolic Math`)

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

expr = parse_expr("sqrt(x)")
print('expr:', expr)

#result = expr.subs({'x': 9}).evalf()
result = expr.evalf(subs={'x': 9})

print('result:', result)

#result = expr.subs({'x': 16}).evalf()
result = expr.evalf(subs={'x': 16})
print('result:', result)
```

Result:

```
expr: sqrt(x)
result: 3.00000000000000
result: 4.00000000000000
```

---

You can use more complex expressions with more variables and with constant values like `pi`

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

#expr = parse_expr("sqrt(x)/2")
#expr = parse_expr("sqrt(x)**2")
#expr = parse_expr("x + sqrt(x) + y**2")
expr = parse_expr("2 * pi * r")  # circle area
print('expr:', expr)

#result = expr.subs({'x': 9, 'y': 2, 'r': 4}).evalf()
result = expr.evalf(subs={'x': 9, 'y': 2, 'r': 4})
print('result:', result)

#result = expr.subs({'x': 16, 'y': 2, 'r': 5}).evalf()
result = expr.evalf(subs={'x': 16, 'y': 2, 'r': 5})
print('result:', result)
```

---

SymPy doc: [parsing](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html)